# Remove class from table th

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to remove class `"sorting"` from the last `<th>` element of given datatable table.

```
<th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="GetLibraryTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 108.009px;" aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending">Action</th>
```

I tried with below code:

```
document.querySelector("#GetLibraryTable_wrapper > div.dataTables_scroll > div.dataTables_scrollHead > div > table > thead > tr > th:nth-child(7)").removeClass('sorting');
```

But this gives below console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).removeClass is not a function

Comment: replace "removeClass('sorting')" with classList.remove("sorting")

Comment: Thats because you use `jquery` in combination with pure `JS`

Comment: try using `classList.remove("sorting")` instead

Answer (score 1):

the **jQuery** solution is:

```
$("#GetLibraryTable_wrapper > div.dataTables_scroll > div.dataTables_scrollHead > div > table > thead > tr > th:nth-child(7)").removeClass('sorting');
```

no **jQuery** plain **Javascript**:

```
document.querySelector("#GetLibraryTable_wrapper > div.dataTables_scroll > div.dataTables_scrollHead > div > table > thead > tr > th:nth-child(7)").classList.remove('sorting');
```

for better selector use **:last-of-type**

```
document.querySelector("#GetLibraryTable_wrapper th:last-of-type").classList.remove('sorting');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "th" ).last().removeClass('sorting');
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="GetLibraryTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 108.009px;" aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending">Id</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="GetLibraryTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 108.009px;" aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending">Action</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Without the addition of CSS it's difficult to tell your snippet works.  Maybe you'd consider adding it

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove class "sorting" from the last  element of given datatable table

To achieve your requirement, you can try this code snippet using `:last-child` selector:

```
document.querySelector("#GetLibraryTable_wrapper > div.dataTables_scroll > div.dataTables_scrollHead > div > table > thead > tr > th:last-child").classList.remove("sorting");
```

More information about css selectors, can refer this doc: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp